# tinymce losing the newlines when submiting a form via frame

Tags: tinymce

I have a configuration (I didn't want it to be wrapped in a paragraph) where I expect newlines in the editor to be submitted as

```
var richtexteditorConfig = { 
  selector: 'textarea.tinymce', 
   forced_root_block: "",
           menubar: false, 
              inline: false, 
   remove_linebreaks: false, 
   force_br_newlines: true, 
   force_p_newlines: false, 
   convert_newlines_to_brs: true, 
            branding: false, 
  plugins: [ 
    'link' 
  ], 
  toolbar: [ 
'undo redo | bold italic underline strikethrough | alignleft aligncenter alignright alignjustify |     numlist bullist | forecolor backcolor casechange permanentpen formatpainter removeformat link'  ], 
  valid_elements: 'p[style],strong,em,span[style],a[href],ul,ol,li', 
  valid_styles: { 
    '*': 'font-size,font-family,color,text-decoration,text-align' 
  }
}; 
tinymce.init(richtexteditorConfig);
```

However when I submit the form using a frame it strips out those newlines.  It keeps some stuff like bolding and colors but I always lose the newlines.  Is there somemething magical I need to do, it needs to be submitted with teh rest of the elements and right now I am just doing:

```
dojo.require('dojo.io.iframe'); 
    dojo.io.iframe.send({  
        url: 'MyUrl',  
        handleAs: "text",
        method: 'POST',  
        form: dojo.byId(formid),   
       load: function(response, ioArgs){  
            eval(response);
            return response;  
       },  
       error: function(response, ioArgs){  
           console.log('error sending ' + response);     
           return response;  
       }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

seems like it is the

```
   forced_root_block: ""
```

causing all the problems.